# Internal implementation of "makeStyles" in React Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The purpose of this question is to understand what is happening under the hood. Every time I found the code with `makeStyles()` I feel that I am just doing a pure copy paste without understanding what is happening under the hood. So I thought of posting a question here so that some one can help me out.

I have seen the below kind of code in many React apps. I was so curious to know what is happening when we make a call to `makeStyles()`. So I jumped into its definition but I am not able to understand what does it mean. Can someone help me understand how to read/understand it.

What I understand here is that I am passing a function with parameter named `theme`. After passing that function I have no clue what is going on. I appreciate if some one help me figure out this as well.

```
// Calling makeStyles()
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  drawer: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      flexShrink: 0,
    },
  },
  appBar: {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    },
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

//definition of makeStyles()
import { Theme as DefaultTheme } from './createMuiTheme';
import { Styles, WithStylesOptions } from '@material-ui/styles/withStyles';
import { StylesHook } from '@material-ui/styles/makeStyles';

export default function makeStyles<
  Theme = DefaultTheme,
  Props extends {} = {},
  ClassKey extends string = string
>(
  styles: Styles<Theme, Props, ClassKey>,
  options?: WithStylesOptions<Theme>,
): StylesHook<Styles<Theme, Props, ClassKey>>;
```

Answer (score 18):

### High-level picture of inputs/outputs/side effects

**makeStyles**

- overview: This function is typically called at the top-level within a JavaScript file (not from within a component/function), and it returns a function (typically called `useStyles`) that will be used from within a function component.
- input: styles object or styles object creator function

  - If the input is an object, it is assumed that each property of the object defines a style rule. The property name is the rule name and the property value is an object with CSS properties and/or nested rules. Each style rule will later be used to generate a CSS class.
  - If the input is a function, it is assumed to be a function that receives the theme as an argument and then returns a styles object with the structure described in the case where the input is an object.
  - In the [makeStyles function declaration](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/makeStyles.js#L186), this input is called `stylesOrCreator`. This is then normalized by the [getStylesCreator function](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui-styles/src/getStylesCreator/getStylesCreator.js#L10) to be an object with a `create` property that points at a function which will return a styles object.
- output: `useStyles` function

  - The function [returned](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/makeStyles.js#L206) by `makeStyles` is typically called `useStyles` and is a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook). This means that it can only be called from within a function component and [must be called unconditionally](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level).
  - At the point of returning this `useStyles` function, very little has happened. The function knows about its [stylesCreator](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/makeStyles.js#L220), but hasn't used it yet. Via the [stylesCreator's options](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/makeStyles.js#L199), the `useStyles` function knows an `index` that will later be used to determine the location in the `<head>` of the style sheet for these styles relative to the other style sheets generated by other calls to `makeStyles`/`useStyles`.
- side effect: increments a [global counter](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/indexCounter.js) that is used to determine the index within the `<head>` of style sheets generated by `makeStyles/useStyles`.

**useStyles**

- overview: This is the function returned by `makeStyles`. It should be called from within a function component to get a `classes` object described below.
- optional input: `props` object

  - If passed, this is typically the `props` of the function component this is used in. This will then be passed as an argument to any style rules where the value is a function.
  - You can see examples of using this in the following answers:

    - [Send Variable to withStyles in Material UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54832736/send-variable-to-withstyles-in-material-ui/54833315#54833315)
    - [Using props to set '&:hover' background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55008320/using-props-to-set-hover-background-color/55010155#55010155)
    - [How to use 'theme' and 'props' in makeStyles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56111294/how-to-use-theme-and-props-in-makestyles/56114885#56114885)
- output: `classes` object

  - This object maps each style rule name in your styles object to a generated CSS class name. You can then leverage `classes.rulename` in your component rendering to apply that CSS class to an element.
- side effect: Adds a style sheet to the DOM in the `<head>` containing a CSS class per style rule.

### Where the main work occurs

The bulk of the magic happens when you call the `useStyles` function. The beginning of the function is [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/makeStyles.js#L207). Here are the key steps it performs:

- Calls [attach](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/makeStyles.js#L225). The [attach function](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/makeStyles.js#L52) does the following key steps:

  - Calls [stylesCreator.create](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/makeStyles.js#L85) to get your styles object.
  - Leverages [JSS](https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.23) to [create a style sheet](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/makeStyles.js#L88) based on your styles object. It is also within here that JSS generates the class names that will be in the `classes` object.
  - [Attaches](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/makeStyles.js#L92) this style sheet to the DOM at the appropriate location within the `<head>`.
- [Returns the classes object](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/makeStyles.js#L241)
- If something happens to trigger re-creating the CSS or if the component unmounts, then [detach](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/makeStyles.js#L230) is called to remove the previously generated style sheet.

Comment: Is it possible to reuse the useStyles in another component? I mean, if I export this hook and use it in several components, will it be ok?

Comment: @MichaelGustus Yes, but with some caveats. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56929702/material-ui-v4-makestyles-exported-from-a-single-file-doesnt-retain-the-styles/56941531#56941531.

Answer (score 0):

makeStyles(styles, [options]) => hook
Link a style sheet with a function component using the hook pattern.

Arguments

1. styles (Function | Object): A function generating the styles or a styles object. It will be linked to the component. Use the function signature if you need to have access to the theme. It's provided as the first argument.
2. options (Object [optional]):
   options.defaultTheme (Object [optional]):

   1.The default theme to use if a theme isn't supplied through a Theme Provider.

   2. options.name (String [optional]): The name of the style sheet. Useful for 
      debugging. If the value isn't provided, it will try to fallback to the name 
      of the component.
   3. options.flip (Boolean [optional]): When set to false, this sheet will opt- 
      out the rtl transformation. When set to true, the styles are inversed. When 
      set to null, it follows theme.direction.

   The other keys are forwarded to the options argument of 
   [jss.createStyleSheet([styles], [options]).](https://cssinjs.org/jss-api/#create-style-sheet).
   Returns
   hook: A hook. This hook can be used in a function component. The documentation often calls this returned hook useStyles. It accepts one argument: the properties that will be used for "interpolation" in the style sheet.

Examples

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    color: props => props.color,
  },
});

export default function MyComponent(props) {
   const classes = useStyles(props);
   return <div className={classes.root} />;  
}
```