# What does the symbol '&$checked' mean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jss

```
import React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import { createMuiTheme, makeStyles, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { orange } from '@material-ui/core/colors';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    color: theme.status.danger,
    '&$checked': {
      color: theme.status.danger,
    },
  },
  checked: {},
}));

function CustomCheckbox() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Checkbox
      defaultChecked
      classes={{
        root: classes.root,
        checked: classes.checked,
      }}
    />
  );
}

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  status: {
    danger: orange[500],
  },
});

export default function CustomStyles() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CustomCheckbox />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

What does the symbol '&$checked' mean used in [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8mkni)?
Please explain the meaning of each symbol in detail, and the related logic.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `&` is a reference to the parent rule ("root" in this case). `$ruleName` (where "ruleName" is "checked" in this case) references a local rule in the same style sheet.

To clarify some of the terms above, the parameter to `makeStyles` is used to generate a style sheet potentially with multiple style rules. Each object key (e.g. "root", "checked") is referred to as a "rule name". When you call `useStyles` the resulting `classes` object contains a mapping of each rule name to a generated CSS class name.

So in this case let's say that the generated class name for "root" is "root-generated-1" and the generated class name for "checked" is "checked-generated-2", then `&$checked` is equivalent to `.root-generated-1.checked-generated-2` meaning it will match an element that has both the `root` and `checked` classes applied to it.

As far as the effect on the `Checkbox`, the "checked" class is [applied to the `Checkbox`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.7.2/packages/material-ui/src/internal/SwitchBase.js#L110) by Material-UI when it is in a "checked" state. This style rule is overriding the [default color of a checked Checkbox](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.7.2/packages/material-ui/src/Checkbox/Checkbox.js#L42) (the default is the secondary color in the theme).

Related answers and documentation:

- https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.0.0#use--to-reference-selector-of-the-parent-rule
- https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.0.0#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet
- [Internal implementation of "makeStyles" in React Material-UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220059/internal-implementation-of-makestyles-in-react-material-ui/57226057#57226057)

Comment: Your answer is great. I would also like to ask the meaning of the single quotes in '& $ checked'. Is there any documentation? Sorry, maybe I am too horny.

Comment: The single quotes are just JavaScript syntax for defining a String.

Answer (score 1):

'&$checked' means you can override the element after checked.

**And in your case, you are overriding the colour of checkbox after checked it**

```
"&$checked": {
      color: theme.status.danger
    }
```

PFA for detail

[image: I've overridden the colour into the green after checked the box]

Answer (score -5):

You are probably referring to the `.color>*:checked` element