# Selecting second child div while hovering on first child div in makeStyles Material UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, makestyles

I have a parent div and two child divs, I want to apply CSS to the second child div when I hover on the first child div. This is the structure of the render method.

```
<div className={classes.parent}>
    <div className={classes.child1}></div>
    <div className={classes.child2}></div>
</div>
```

What is the material UI's makeStyles syntax for selecting child classes on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`element+element`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) selector to select the element after the current element:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  parent: {
    //
  },
  child1: {
    "&:hover + *": {
      // change the background color of child-2 when hovering on child-1
      backgroundColor: "red"
    }
  },
  child2: {
    //
  }
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67190862/selecting-second-child-div-while-hovering-on-first-child-div-in-makestyles-mater]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for. Can you direct me to some documentation of JSS selectors? I can't seem to find anything online. I have seen `$` also being used in certain places but I am not sure what it means.

Comment: @user8109438 About the dollar sign, you can read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59243783/9449426) here for more info. [JSS documentation](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.6.0#use--to-reference-selector-of-the-parent-rule). You can also see all CSS selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).