# Change color of selected row on Material UI table

Tags: material-ui

How to change/customize the default color of selected rows in a Material-UI table (of type Sorting & Selecting)? By default it is secondary (red) color (Codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/3sjxh). How to change it to a custom color, or at least to primary (blue), as it appears in the new beta version (https://next.material-ui.com/components/tables/#main-content) (v5).

[image: Table with selected row in default red color]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass your styles to the `classes` props in order to change the styles for the `TableRow`.

To achieve the `background-color` change you want to override the default classes: `.MuiTableRow-root.Mui-selected` and `.MuiTableRow-root.Mui-selected:hover`.

To override them you have to use a parent reference with a so called $ruleName in your `makeStyles` hook. [Here is a very good explanation from @Ryan Cogswell if you are more interested how it works.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59243783/what-does-the-symbol-checked-mean)

This would then look like this:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  // your other styles
  ...,
  tableRowRoot: {
    "&$tableRowSelected, &$tableRowSelected:hover": {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main
    }
  },
  tableRowSelected: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main
  }
}));

...

<TableRow
  // your other props
  ...
  classes={{
    root: classes.tableRowRoot,
    selected: classes. tableRowSelected,
  }}
>
  ...
</TableRow>;
```

For the checkboxes, you only have to add the `color` prop in order to change it:

```js
<Checkbox
  // other props
  ...
  color="primary"
/>
```

and for your `Toolbar`, you only need to change the provided `highlight` class inside your `useToolbarStyles` in order to get things working:

```js
import { alpha } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

...

const useToolbarStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  ...,
  highlight:
    theme.palette.type === "light"
      ? {
          color: theme.palette.primary.main,
          backgroundColor: alpha(
            theme.palette.primary.light,
            theme.palette.action.selectedOpacity
          )
        }
      : {
          color: theme.palette.text.primary,
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark
        },
}));
```

### Live demo:

[image: Edit change-color-of-selected-row-on-material-ui-table]

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought it was pointing in that direction but didn't know about $ruleName. And thanks for the link too, very informative indeed!