# What exactly is makeStyles in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I just started learning React [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/) and I found this `makeStyles` function, and they said it returns a Hook.

I remember from React hooks that a custom hook is made by wrapping a built-in hook. I tried looking inside `makeStyles`, and it has some interoperability and some css-in-javascript pattern.

I am really fed up with rules coming over and over again. For now can someone please tell me what is this `makeStyle` function and perhaps suggest a better approach to reading about material-ui.

Thank you good people of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220059/internal-implementation-of-makestyles-in-react-material-ui/57226057#57226057

Answer (score 10):

If you are familiar with the older version of Material-UI, you might have used **withStyles**, to use your custom styles in MUI components.

withStyles is just a HOC(Higher Order Component), used as a wrapper, to assign the **classes** prop to your component. You can furthur use the classes object to assign specific classes to your DOM or MUI elements in your component.

**makeStyles** is just a successor, which returns a hook(to access the custom classes). Now this is only a modern-react way of doing things in order to avoid HOCs.

**MUI v3.9.3**

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = {
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <div className={this.props.classes.root} />;
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent);
```

**MUI v4.9.5**

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
});

export default function MyComponent(props) {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return <div className={classes.root} />;
}
```

Comment: thank you for replying,so it is a successor which returns a hook by using    inbuilt-hook(under hood)? how would i know what it takes as argument , what it returns and what is design pattern of doing this?

Comment: So as you can see.. it takes a simple argument, an object of class names, with their styles.. So its basically styles represented in SCSS..

It is an CSS in JS kind of approach. you can use styles in your component with out any external stylesheets(css or scss)

Comment: @BarunPatro "a CSS in JS kind of approach" ... this reads like a reinvention of [JSSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Style_Sheets) to me ;-)

Comment: dear barun, thank you for your efforts. please avoid the many "just" "basically" "simply" - it improves your posts.