# How to allow customization of a React component's style via props, when withStyles api is used?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm writing some simple reusable component for our React(with MaterialUI) application.

The problem is, that i want to allow different styles of this **same reusable component**, to be customized via props, by the consuming component.

This is some of the code:

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const styles = theme => ({
image: {
    maxHeight: '200px'
}
});

render() {
        const classes = this.props.classes
        return (
            <div>
                 ...
                 <img className={classes.image} src={this.state.filePreviewSrc} alt="" />
                 ...
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Let's say, i want to allow the programmer to customize the appearance of classes.image. Can the hard-coded image class be overwritten somehow?

Is using withStyles api is even the correct approach, for creating components **whose appearance can be customized by the consuming component/programmer?**

Comment: Take a look at styles interpolation https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-based-on-props

Comment: I see that it uses the makeStyles api. Can it be used, in the same fashion, with the withStyles api?

Comment: Sadly still no: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8726 You can always use inline styles for dynamic styles: `style={{color : props.color}}`

Comment: `withStyles` supports props in the same manner as `makeStyles`. In v4, `withStyles` is just a wrapper around `makeStyles`. https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.6.0/packages/material-ui-styles/src/withStyles/withStyles.js#L38

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three main approaches available for how to support customization of styles:

1. Leverage props within your styles
2. Leverage props to determine whether or not certain classes should be applied
3. Do customization via `withStyles`

For option 3, the styles of the wrapping component will be merged with the original, but the CSS classes of the wrapping component will occur later in the `<head>` and will win over the original.

Below is an example showing all three approaches:

**ReusableComponent.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = {
  root: props => ({
    backgroundColor: props.rootBackgroundColor
      ? props.rootBackgroundColor
      : "green"
  }),
  inner: props => ({
    backgroundColor: props.innerBackgroundColor
      ? props.innerBackgroundColor
      : "red"
  })
};

const ReusableComponent = ({ classes, children, suppressInnerDiv = false }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      Outer div
      {suppressInnerDiv && <div>{children}</div>}
      {!suppressInnerDiv && (
        <div className={classes.inner}>
          Inner div
          <div>{children}</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default withStyles(styles)(ReusableComponent);
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import ReusableComponent from "./ReusableComponent";

const styles1 = theme => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
    margin: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  inner: {
    minHeight: 100,
    backgroundColor: "yellow"
  }
});
const Customization1 = withStyles(styles1)(ReusableComponent);

const styles2 = {
  inner: {
    backgroundColor: "purple",
    color: "white"
  }
};
const Customization2 = withStyles(styles2)(ReusableComponent);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReusableComponent>Not customized</ReusableComponent>
      <Customization1>Customization 1 via withStyles</Customization1>
      <Customization2>Customization 2 via withStyles</Customization2>
      <ReusableComponent rootBackgroundColor="lightgrey" suppressInnerDiv>
        Customization via props
      </ReusableComponent>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit styling reusable component]